# Anywhere to get a list of referrer spammers?

Tags: spam, referrer

I do my own log processing using my own self-written analyzer. That means I have to deal with the continual nuisance of referrer spammers. Is there anywhere I can get an up-to-date list of referrer spammers?

Comment: Interesting question, seems like a central registry of referrer spammers could be put together like the email spam blacklists.

Comment: Are you publishing your access logs?

Comment: I'd be willing to share the list of referrer spammers I've got with other people if there was a repository of some kind, but I wouldn't publish my access logs under any circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this subject was [raised in the blogosphere](http://underscorebleach.net/jotsheet/2005/01/referrer-spam-proposal#mt-blacklist) around 5 years ago, but nothing appears to have come of it. It may well be worth exploring the idea again, but I have no idea if the sheer size of the problem would make it unmanageable.